# Convert JSON camel case to snake case (and vice versa) and stringify numeric values

Tags: c#, json, json.net, camelcasing

I have to send and receive JSON objects to a web REST service. The objects are produced by a DLL that serializes the attribute names in upper camel case ("PropertyName"), and the web service wants snake case ("property_name").
Plus, the DLL serializes numeric values as floating point numbers, but the REST APIs want all strings.
After processing the object, the REST service returns snake case JSON.

The JSON is complex and contains nested arrays and objects. While converting back from the REST string, I can skip the de-stringification of the numeric strings, but I still have to reconvert the attribute names to upper camel case.

I was thinking of writing a helper class using the Newtonsoft Json library, but it looks trickier than I expected. The converter should accept JSON and return JSON.

Example:

```
{
    "FirstObject": {
        "NestedObject": {
            "AttributeString": "ok",
            "AttributeNumeric": 123.45
        },
        "OtherObject": [{
            "ArrayVal": 100
        }, {
            "ArrayVal": 200
        }]
    }
}
```

should become

```
{
    "first_object": {
        "nested_object": {
            "attribute_string": "ok",
            "attribute_numeric": "123.45"
        },
        "other_object": [{
            "array_val": "100"
        }, {
            "array_val": "200"
        }]
    }
}
```

I see that the Json.Net library has `SnakeCaseNamingStrategy` and `CamelCaseNamingStrategy` classes, so the idea was using a `JsonTextReader` to parse the input, change the naming convention of the property names, set numeric values as string, and write the modified tokens using a `JsonTextWriter`.

I could not find any sample on how to do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way to do what you want is to use a set of model classes that match your JSON.  (You can generate the classes in Visual Studio by copying a complete sample of the JSON to the clipboard and then using the `Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as Classes` function.)  Make the model classes use upper camel case for the property names (which is the standard naming convention of C# anyway), and use strings in place of numeric properties.

So, for your example JSON, the model classes would look like this:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public FirstObject FirstObject { get; set; }
}

public class FirstObject
{
    public NestedObject NestedObject { get; set; }
    public List<OtherObject> OtherObject { get; set; }
}

public class NestedObject
{
    public string AttributeString { get; set; }
    public string AttributeNumeric { get; set; }
}

public class OtherObject
{
    public string ArrayVal { get; set; }  // using string instead of int here
}
```

Then, to convert from the upper camel case JSON to snake case, you can do this:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
    {
        NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy { ProcessDictionaryKeys = true }
    },
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented
};
json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, settings);
```

The original JSON will deserialize to the model naturally because the property names already match.  Json.Net will automatically convert the numeric values in the JSON  to strings as needed to fit the class properties.  On serialization, the `SnakeCaseNamingStrategy` comes into play to change the property names to snake case.  The numeric values are written out as strings because that's the way the properties are declared in the classes.

To go back the other way, you would do:

```
obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json, settings);  // same settings as above
json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented);
```

Here, during deserialization, Json.Net uses the `SnakeCaseNamingStrategy` to convert the model property names to snake case again to match them up with the JSON properties.  The numeric values are already strings in the JSON so there's no conversion needed.  On serialization, we aren't using any special settings, so the property names are written out exactly as declared, which is upper camel case.  The string properties holding numeric values remain strings (you said this was OK in your question).

Here is a round-trip demo:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/3Pb1fT

---

If you don't have a model to work with, it's still possible to do this conversion using the `JsonReader`/`JsonWriter` approach you suggested, but it will take a little more code to glue them together and do the transformations.  Here is a helper method that will do the bulk of the heavy lifting:

```
public static void ConvertJson(TextReader textReader, TextWriter textWriter, 
                               NamingStrategy strategy, 
                               Formatting formatting = Formatting.Indented)
{
    using (JsonReader reader = new JsonTextReader(textReader))
    using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(textWriter))
    {
        writer.Formatting = formatting;
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.None)
        {
            reader.Read();
            ConvertJsonValue(reader, writer, strategy);
        }
    }
}

private static void ConvertJsonValue(JsonReader reader, JsonWriter writer, 
                                     NamingStrategy strategy)
{
    if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
    {
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        while (reader.Read() && reader.TokenType != JsonToken.EndObject)
        {
            string name = strategy.GetPropertyName((string)reader.Value, false);
            writer.WritePropertyName(name);
            reader.Read();
            ConvertJsonValue(reader, writer, strategy);
        }
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
    else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
    {
        writer.WriteStartArray();
        while (reader.Read() && reader.TokenType != JsonToken.EndArray)
        {
            ConvertJsonValue(reader, writer, strategy);
        }
        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }
    else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Integer)
    {
        // convert integer values to string
        writer.WriteValue(Convert.ToString((long)reader.Value));
    }
    else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Float)
    {
        // convert floating point values to string
        writer.WriteValue(Convert.ToString((double)reader.Value,
                          System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));        
    }
    else // string, bool, date, etc.
    {
        writer.WriteValue(reader.Value);
    }
}
```

To use it, you just need to set up a `TextReader` for your input JSON and a `TextWriter` for the output, and pass in the appropriate `NamingStrategy` you want to use for the conversion.  For example, to convert your original JSON string to snake case, you would do this:

```
using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(upperCamelCaseJson))
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
{
    ConvertJson(sr, sw, new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy(), formatting);
    string snakeCaseJson = sw.ToString();
    ...
}
```

Or, if the source and/or destination for your JSON is a stream of some sort, you can use a `StreamReader`/`StreamWriter` instead:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(inputStream))
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(outputStream))
{
    ConvertJson(sr, sw, new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy(), formatting);
}
```

Now, for the return trip, there is bit of an issue. A `NamingStrategy` only works in one direction; it doesn't provide a facility for reversing the conversion.  That means none of the Newtonsoft-supplied `NamingStrategy` classes will work for converting snake case back to upper camel case the way you want.  The `CamelCaseNamingStrategy` won't work because it doesn't expect to start with snake case (it wants upper camel case), and its output isn't upper camel anyway.  The `DefaultNamingStrategy` won't work either, because it doesn't actually do any conversion at all--it's just a pass-through.

The solution is to make your own custom `NamingStrategy`.  Fortunately this isn't difficult to do.  Just derive from the base `NamingStrategy` class and implement the abstract `ResolvePropertyName` method:

```
// This naming strategy converts snake case names to upper camel case (a.k.a. proper case)
public class ProperCaseFromSnakeCaseNamingStrategy : NamingStrategy
{
    protected override string ResolvePropertyName(string name)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(name.Length);
        for (int i = 0; i < name.Length; i++)
        {
            char c = name[i];

            if (i == 0 || name[i - 1] == '_')
                c = char.ToUpper(c);

            if (c != '_')
                sb.Append(c);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Now you can pass this new strategy to the `ConvertJson` method as described above to convert the snake case JSON back to upper camel case.

Round-trip demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jt0XKD

Comment: Thank you Brian. This is really interesting for me, as I am quite new to the handling of json objects in .Net. The only problem I see is the objects here are quite complex (it is the new electronic invoice that will be mandatory in Italy starting next January). Most of the time, the data will be just a small subset of the full type definition. I don't even have a full prototype of the spec in json (I have it in xml). Hence the idea of the JsonTextReader/Write approach. Anyway, you have given me a good hint on which I will work during the weekend.

Comment: Thank you again, Brian. You saved me a lot of headaches. I tried it both ways and works like a charm. I only had to create a Dictonary in the ProperCaseFromSnakeCaseNamingStrategy override to handle some tokens with unconventional casing (e.g. "AliquotaIVA" snakized as "aliquota_iva" but then recamelized as "AliquotaIva").

Comment: One small thing to note, in case anybody needs to stringify floats: if you are on a European localized system, Brian's code will use the comma as decimal separator. Easily fixed just changing this part of ConvertJsonValue():
        `else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Float)
        {
            // convert floating point values to string
            writer.WriteValue(Convert.ToString((double)reader.Value,
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        }`

Comment: Good catch on the decimal conversion.  I've edited that into the answer above.