# Convert string JSON to Camel Case

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm getting my input data in camel and pascal case. before putting business logic I want to convert input data into a single case.

I did below code (it's working). It doesn't look good when I think about performance.

```
string message = "{JSON in pascal or camel case}";
var interimObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(message);
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(interimObject, Formatting.Indented,new JsonSerializerSettings
                  {
                      ContractResolver = AppConfiguration.CamelCaseResolver
                  });
JObject alertMessage = JObject.Parse(json);
alertMessage.Add("id", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());//correlation-Id
```

Is there any better way??

Comment: Why are you getting data in with several formats? It isn’t possible to fix the parts that are producing the wrong output? Or let JSON.net just handle it?

Comment: Existing application produce data in camel and pascal case. I have a single endpoint for all. I have some if else condition so I need to fix case issue.

Comment: *I did below code (it's working). It doesn't look good when I think about performance.* -- if it's working, them what is your question?  How to avoid having to construct a complete `interimObject` in memory?

Comment: If you simply want to avoid constructing `interimObject` you can adapt the method `ConvertJson(TextReader textReader, TextWriter textWriter, NamingStrategy strategy, Formatting formatting)` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53783120/3744182) to [Convert JSON camel case to snake case (and vice versa) and stringify numeric values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53779796/3744182) by [Brian Rogers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10263/brian-rogers).  In fact your question may be a duplicate; agree?